# How to mention wildcard in ansible commands

Tags: linux, ansible

I am executing shell commands via Ansible.

Sometimes i don't have the complete foldername. Suppose i have dirname  `solr4.7.0`.

In shell I can type `cd solr*`.

But in ansible I can't do:

`chdir=/var/solr*`

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  The `chdir=` parameter to, e.g., the `command` module does not support wildcards.

You could accomplish what you want using a [register variable](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) to store the output of the `ls` command:

```
- shell: ls -d solr*
  register: dir_name
- command: some_command
  args:
    chdir: "{{ dir_name.stdout }}"
```

But this is, frankly, an ugly solution.  You're better off just using the actual directory name.  If it differs on different hosts, you can use host variables to set it appropriately.

Comment: Actually, I find this brilliant. There are times that you have no idea what a downloaded archive's build number is in it.

Comment: If you just need the globbed output, using `echo solr*` would expand without invoking `ls`, since `ls` sometimes does unexpected things like colors, -F marks, ...

Answer (score 7):

As Larsks wrote the key is to use `register`, but the code was not working on my current ansible version. So here is corrected one:

```
- shell: ls -d solr*
  register: dir_name

- command: chdir={{ item }} some_command
  with_items: dir_name.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ansible on the command line to execute ad hoc commands, a wildcard is very useful, e.g. to see if a file exists on all systems.

I too struggled to do:
`$ ansible production -a "ls /mypath/*xxx*"`

But wrapping it in bash -c '...' works:
`$ ansible production -a "bash -c 'ls /mypath/*xxx*'"`

Answer (score 3):

A task defined like this would do the trick:

```
- name: Move internal directories and files
  command: bash -c 'mv /tmp/parent-dir/*  /opt/destination/'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of hacky, but I have found that if you put the commands that use a wildcard into a script, and then use the ansible 'script' command to run that script, the wildcards are fine.

```html
- name: "some command that needs to use a wildcard"
  script: /script_containing_wildcard_commands.sh
```